# Forbidden error coming on delete image on main server,localhost:its working fine

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have developed a website.On 1 page there is a picture gallery,images are getting uploaded perfectly but as soon as i delete an image,this error comes:

***Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /fdccms/backend/project_categories/view_image.php on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.***
Deleting an image is working perfectly on localhost but i don't know the problem with server.
In .htaccess also i have included rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^view_image/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ http://fdc-int.com/fdccms/backend/project_categories/view_image.php?id=$1&del=$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your folder permissions. Make sure you have read, write and execute permissions for that folder. (that would be 777)

if it's your `.htaccess`, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^view_image/([^/]*)/?(.*) /backend/project_categories/view_image.php?id=$1&del=$2 [L]
```

since you said fdccms is your webroot.

either way the `$` is un-needed since the `.` matches any character.

Comment: Sorry,if that seems a silly question,But as i am new to php,i want to ask the folder permissions u talking about is for the images folder? right?...that is 777 but no result....i have added an [L] too but that also not working...

Comment: You will need to check the permissions on every folder in the hierarchy to make sure you can write in the directory.

Comment: Yeah...the attributes are 777...images are uploading easily..but to delete that forbidden error is coming

Comment: what code are you using to delete the file? could it be your web host doesn't allow the function?

Comment: I am using this code:

***if(isset($_GET['del']))
{
//get image name
$img =  $_GET['del'];
$img = strrchr($img, '/' );
$img = substr($img, 1);
$imagefile = substr($img,0);
 // remove from akhbar_detail table
 $query = "DELETE FROM projectscategories_pic WHERE image = '$img'";
 mysql_query($query) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
@unlink($_GET['del']);
/* This will give an error. Note the output
 * above, which is before the header() call */
header("Location: view_image.php?id=$_GET[id]");
}***


           
<?
}

Comment: your code seems ok so it's probably your htaccess, I'll change my answer after reading some comments you've made on other posts

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have some trouble with your rewriteRule.

Probably **?(.*)** does not work as expected. The QUERY_STRING should be added automatically, but sometimes that does not happen. I am not sure, if it does not work, if there is a ? in the Rewrite Target.

so try this:

```
RewriteRule ^view_image/([^/]*)/ /backend/project_categories/view_image.php?id=$1&del=%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: this request would work: http://fdc-int.com/fdccms/backend/project_categories/view_image.php?id=1&del=2 ? Or you want only an internal redirect, than you cannot use the http://  try this: RewriteRule ^view_image/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ fdccms/backend/project_categories/view_image.php?id=$1&del=$2 [L] (well, fdccms should be in your webroot then)

Comment: fdccms in my webroot...i did that....but no result..i have tried almost everything...

Comment: i still guess, you have trouble with the .htaccess. I changed my answer a bit. And please check your Code for SQL injection issue (which is in there now) and check $_GET['del'] if it only removes correct files. Null-Bytes are allowed in PHP but will be ignored in file-functions.

Comment: Everything is working fine in localhost infact,the same code i have used on other servers for other websites,they are working perfectly,but the problem is there with this server only.

Comment: check if $_GET['del'] has any value if (isset($_GET['del']) && $_GET['del'] == '') die('oops, the parameter is there, but empty'); -> you have trouble with your RewriteRule. Replace your Code with an Debug Code, which returns your values.